# how to open multiple textboxes on a click using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

```
<table>
  <tbody id="eb_body">
    <tr>
      <td>Booking Bills:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="e_brochure0" name="e_brochure0" placeholder="From           Bill No........" required/></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a onClick="add_brochures()" style="text-decoration:none !important;"><span style="cursor:pointer; font-size:10px; ">+Add more bill nos.</span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="save" name="save" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

there is an anchor tag on that click i am calling a  function as below..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var b=1;
function add_brochures()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

            document.getElementById("zone").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","five.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    b=b+1;

}
</script>
```

with this i am directing the page to five.php where i am displaying a select box....

code for five.php is this...

```
<?php
include 'dbcon.php';
$sql="select * from tb_zone";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
?> 
<tr>
<td>

<select>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        ?>
        <option>
        <?php echo $row["zone_name"]; ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>

</td>
</tr>
```

when i click on anchor tag it is opening one selectbox but bot more....what i want is that when i click on anchor tag then a selectbox appears...if i click on it 5 times then i should open selectbox 5 times....right now it is opening just 1 selectbox....please help

Comment: see this link. It may help you http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/

Comment: Since you're setting `innerHTML`, not concatenating it, it replaces the old contents. Use `+=` instead of `=` if you want to append.

Comment: actaully i have to include php script on selectbox that is why i  am using ajax

Comment: @barmer....where i have to make this change/?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
document.getElementById("zone").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("zone").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
```

`+=` will concatenate the response to the existing HTML, which will add a new row to the table.

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: sir actually it is displaying multiple selectboxes on anchor tag ...for eg i clicked on anchor and the selectbox gets displayed ...i choose some value...and when i click again on anchor tag to choose one more value then the value that i choose above gets blank...then again i have to choose...means when i clcik on anchor tag to open new selectbox the previous values gets vanished...?? what can be done for that/?

Comment: That's because you're rewriting the inner HTML of the table, so all the state is lost. It would be better if you created new elements, and  added them with `appendChild`. I know how to do that with jQuery, I'm not sure how to do it with plain Javascript.

Comment: i want to insert all these values in database...so will it be possible with jquery??

Comment: Yes. jQuery is just a library that makes it easier to write Javascript.

Comment: could you please tell me how to do it with jquery then...it is a very important topic for me??